# Getting GroupContact Members from PublicGroup within Global Address List (EWS)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When sending emails to distribution lists, the lists themselves are found within the Global Address List (GAL). Accessing the GAL within Outlook 2010 is a simple matter of popping into your address book and selecting the appropriate address book (in this case, the GAL for the logged in user).

I've tried and tried to get access to the Members of a ContactGroup within the GAL but it doesn't appear to have an ID (and as such, no UniqueID either). It comes up as a MailboxType of MailboxType.PublicGroup from within the ToRecipients property of a sent email, but I can't find out how to access the actual contact addresses!

Anyone know how I can get a hold of them? I've tried doing public folder searches, full Contacts searched but nothing seems to find it.

Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS is not the right tool for the job. You need to query ActiveDirectory. See http://www.infinitec.de/post/2005/02/How-to-get-the-Global-Address-List-programatically.aspx for an example.

Comment: I thought that might be the case! I'll have a look

Comment: This answer is not right. This is possible please check the answer of WFY. His code is working great.

Answer (score 4):

I use Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.1 SDK and it works like a charm.
Replace `<exchange_server>` and `<group_name>` with your own one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace test3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ExchangeService service = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Url = new Uri("https://<exchange_server>/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NameResolutionCollection nameResolutions = service.ResolveName(
                "<group_name>",
                ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,
                true);

            foreach (NameResolution nameResolution in nameResolutions)
            {
                ExpandGroupResults groupResults = service.ExpandGroup(nameResolution.Mailbox.Address);
                foreach (EmailAddress member in groupResults.Members)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(member.Name + " <" + member.Address + ">");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would group name be though?